# System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Cannot able to find the uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have 2 web servers providing load balance service. Each IIS host has a temporary folder D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder\ to placed uploaded file. When user submit to upload a file, it will upload file to UploadFolder, then move the uploaded file to a permanent storage. It happened that if user's request is direct to Server1, it got the following exception

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder\G201323200010081.txt'. File name:
>   'D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder\G201323200010081.txt'    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
>   at PTS_MAM3.Web.DataSource.WSARCHIVE.fileMove(ClassUploadFileClass x,
>   String scase) in
>   E:\PTSMAM_Source\PTS_MAM\PTS_MAM3.Web\DataSource\WSARCHIVE.asmx.cs:line
>   1655

But the file "D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder\G201323200010081.txt" exist in its folder.

If i do the upload job in Server2, it works fine. 
Why is that? Is it possible that Server1:D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder and Server2:D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder may differ?

Following is the source code.
I think the exception is induced by
System.IO.File.Move(fileFrom, fileDest);

```
    private bool fileMove(ClassUploadFileClass x, string scase)
    {
        string fileFrom = string.Empty;
        string fileFromV = string.Empty;
        string fileDest = x.strDirectory;
        //string fileDest2 = string.Concat(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDest), @"\", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileDest), "_M", System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileDest));
        string fileDest2 = string.Concat(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDest), @"\", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileDest), "_M.jpg");
        string TempDir = Server.MapPath("/") + @"UploadFolder\";
        //MAM_PTS_DLL.SysConfig obj = new MAM_PTS_DLL.SysConfig();
        //string dirPhoto = obj.sysConfig_Read("/ServerConfig/STO_Config/UPLOAD_FOLDER_PHOTO");
        //string dirDoc = obj.sysConfig_Read("/ServerConfig/STO_Config/UPLOAD_FOLDER_DOC");
        //string dirAudio = obj.sysConfig_Read("/ServerConfig/STO_Config/UPLOAD_FOLDER_AUDIO");

        try
        {
            //MAM_PTS_DLL.Log.AppendTrackingLog("WSARchive/fileMove", MAM_PTS_DLL.Log.TRACKING_LEVEL.INFO, "Path = " + fileDest);// + @"\" + x.strFileId + "." + x.strOExtensionName);
            switch (scase)
            {
                case ("Photo"):
                    fileFrom = string.Concat(TempDir, x.strFileId, ".", x.strOExtensionName);//@"\\10.13.220.2\uploadfolder\Pictures\"
                    //fileFromV = string.Concat(TempDir, x.strFileId, "_M.", x.strOExtensionName);//@"\\10.13.220.2\uploadfolder\Pictures\"
                    fileFromV = string.Concat(TempDir, x.strFileId, "_M.jpg");
                    break;
                case ("Audio"):
                    fileFrom = string.Concat(TempDir, x.strFileId, ".", x.strOExtensionName);//@"\\10.13.220.2\uploadfolder\Audios\"
                    break;
                case ("Doc"):
                    fileFrom = string.Concat(TempDir, x.strFileId, ".", x.strOExtensionName);
                    break;
                case ("LowVideo"):
                    fileFrom = string.Concat(TempDir, x.strFileId, ".", x.strOExtensionName);
                    break;
            }

            string dirPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDest);
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirPath))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
            System.IO.File.Move(fileFrom, fileDest);        // + @"\" + x.strFileId + "." + x.strOExtensionName);

            if (scase == "Photo")
                System.IO.File.Move(fileFromV, fileDest2);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MAM_PTS_DLL.Log.AppendTrackingLog("File Move Problem", MAM_PTS_DLL.Log.TRACKING_LEVEL.ERROR, x.strOFileName + ",ex = " + ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the permissions of the folder. Does the IIS application pool user has access to it (read/write)? If you can, try login as the application pool user and the look at the folder.

Comment: I switch login with application pool user. It can  access the UploadFolder with read/write.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file exists and you checked that it does exists.

1. Right click the folder `D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder`
2. Click on properties and then Security Tab.
3. The Click on edit button
4. Then Click on add button
5. Then add user `IIS_IUSRS` (checkbox full control should be checked) and then click OK

The problem should be fixed now.

**Note** Giving full control is not recommended, so you have to decide on what permission needed, if you have security concerns.

**Other issue** can be since you are using different drive (`D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder`) the code `string TempDir = Server.MapPath("/") + @"UploadFolder\";` will not find correct path

`Server.MapPath` will start finding from the folder which is used to host the web application.

Comment: Thanks @GauravKP, I dump TempDir and it is a correct path **D:\Website\PTSMAM\UploadFolder\**. I also add IIS_IUSRS permission to access UploadFolder, it still doesn't work.